# FOSUserBundle - Creating new user specifying role

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

Would like to know how can achieve the creation of a new user but specifying his role. At the moment, when i created a new user the program automatically associated with ROLE_ADMIN role.

Any information/code/example is very welcome.

Comment: Are you sure that **ROLE_ADMIN** is the default role? That seems strange to me. How are you creating the user?

Comment: I supposed ROLE_ADMIN is the default role, not sure about it. What i usually do to create a new user is going into `/register` and fill the form. Then, check the authentication on symfony debug panel and it shows the ROLE_ADMIN role assigned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok. I solved my problem. Basically i follow [this](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_forms.html) guide, and changed some aspects.

1. On my model, i added the field for roles: `protected $roles = array();`
2. Changed my Form/Type/RegistrationFormType.php and put the following control:

Code:

```
$user = new UserAdmin();
    $builder->add('roles', 'collection', array(
        'type'   => 'choice',
        'options'  => array(
            'choices'  => array(
                'nashville' => 'Nashville',
                'paris'     => 'Paris',
                'berlin'    => 'Berlin',
                'london'    => 'London',
            ),
        ),
));
```

Now when i opened my register view it shows a dropdownlist. In this case the options are: Nashville, Paris, Berlin, London.

Answer (score 4):

This is the code I used:

```
    $admin = new User() ;
    $admin->setEmail("adminl@gmail.com") ;
    $admin->setUsername("mitke") ;
    $admin->setPlainPassword("123123123") ;
    $admin->setEnabled(true) ;
    $admin->setSuperAdmin(true) ;

    $user1 = new User() ;
    $user1->setEmail("user1@gmail.com") ;
    $user1->setUsername("user1") ;
    $user1->setPlainPassword("123123123") ;
    $user1->setEnabled(true) ;
    $user1->setRoles( array(User::ROLE_DEFAULT) ) ;
```

Maybe it can help you, it works for me.

Question:
Does all users you create using /register has admin role? Maybe FOS decides that first registered user will be admin by default.

Comment: I thought it was in that way. But yesterday i tried running the whole register after cleaning my database/cache and the user created was with ROLE_USER role. I will try with your code tonight. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

A solution of James Morris could be helpful:
http://blog.jmoz.co.uk/symfony2-fosuserbundle-roles

More discuss see: [Symfony2 FOSUserBundle Role entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388080/symfony2-fosuserbundle-role-entities)