# symfony setRole from choice in Form end up in an error

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, object, transform

I'm using an entity to catch some role-data into a choice field. This works fine. After sending the form, I can access the value of the choice which looks like:

```
object(Pr\UserBundle\Entity\Group)#1582 (3) { 
      ["id":protected]=> int(2) 
      ["name":protected]=>string(13) "Chief Roca" 
      ["roles":protected]=> string(21) "ROLE_CUSTOMER_MANAGER"
}
```

Now, if I want to save this by

```
$userData ->setRoles($form->get('usergroups')->getData());
```

I end up in the following error

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to FOS\UserBundle\Model\User::setRoles() 
must be of the type array, object given, called in /var/www/symfony/webprojekt/src/Pr/UserBundle/Controller/AdminController.php 
on line 427 and defined in /var/www/symfony/webprojekt/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/Model/User.php line 530
```

How can I handle this? Do I need to encode it? I think, roles will be stored as an array if I'm right but I'm not sure how to get through there :(

Can anyone give me a hint please?

Comment: Seems like you are trying to do the same thing as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388080/symfony2-fosuserbundle-role-entities

Comment: Try `$userData ->setRoles($form->get('usergroups')->getData()->getRoles());` or `$userData ->addRole($form->get('usergroups')->getData()->getRoles());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `FOSUserBundle`'s default entity setup, then its `roles` property should contain a serialized array (that's achieved via the `object` Doctrine field type, so it's totally transparent to work with).

This means that the correct call that should be made to `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User::setRoles()` looks like this:

```
$user->setRoles(array('ROLE_CUSTOMER_MANAGER'));
```

An easy workaround in your case would be to use `array_map`:

```
$userData->setRoles(array_map(function($role) {
    return $role->getRoles();
}, form->get('usergroups')->getData()));
```

Although, I'd suggest reworking the form/model to expose a better and more logical API (e.g. why does *plural* `Pr\UserBundle\Entity\Group`'s `roles` field contain a single string? etc.)

Comment: Kix, Thanky ou very much for this hint. It works.  I will change the model of the entity later on. You're right that it is not well planned.